# How to change eGit location within Configuration?

Tags: eclipse, git, configuration, egit

I can't seem to be able to change the configuration location of my `.gitconfig` file within Eclipse. It's grayed out and I can't even add entries. How can this accomplished?

[image]

Comment: The Git _**User Settings**_ are stored in the `.gitconfig` file in the **user home directory**, which is in your case `Y:\`. The fact that you cannot edit the file is probably due to the file permissions: the Windows user with whom Eclipse is running has no permission to write to that file. Change the file permission or use repository-specific settings (tab _Repository Settings_).

Comment: `Y:` drive used to be a network drive that no longer exists.

Comment: In _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Configuration_ what is `user.home=`?

Comment: It doesn't exist. Because `Y:` and anything in it are non-existent.

Comment: You already said that. But what is the value of the `user.home` system property: see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Configuration_?